# Simple Filter and RLC Circuit Pointer

Tags: filter, frequency, passive-networks, series

If someone could push me in a decent / reasonable direction it would be much appreciated! I do a HNC part time on electrical / electronic engineering and with how busy I have been at work I feel I have missed / forgot crucial parts of this! 
[image: Assignment Requirements]

[image: My Current Progress]

In my working:
f0 = 50
V1 = 350 
V3 = 70
03 = 30
R = 15
L = 250mH

Comment: So, how is the RLC connected to the voltage source and where are you measuring/predicting what the output is? In other words, draw a circuit.

Comment: A very good question! The above is all the information I have!

Comment: Well you can still draw your circuit based on your assumptions.

Comment: My main point of confusion is "fundamental" voltage. Would this be considered V1 + V2?

Comment: Both voltages are sinusoidal. Your plot doesn't make any sense to me. The fundamental is the V1 source, V3 is the third harmonic. In other words the frequency of V3 is three times the frequency of V1.

Comment: Show your work. Solution requires lmpedance of each reactive part at 1f to be the same for PF=1 the the voltage on each part. Q is determined by L/R